# Open data for behavioral psychology experiment?

Tags: experimental-psychology, cognitive-modeling, data

I have a model I'd like to compare to the Drift Diffusion model, which is commonly used to model response times and error rates in two-alternative forced-choice tasks.  Lots of publications use the random dot motion task like this [1] or this [2] and collect response-time data.

My question is - does anyone know of publicly available response time datasets that I could use for model comparison?

[1] https://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/Ch16.S1.html

[2] https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Random-dot-motion-task-a-An-array-of-dots-is-moving-into-random-directions-with-a_fig2_226279128

Answer (score 2):

There are some example data sets associated with these tutorials https://osf.io/pbwx8/

See 'get_all_data.R' in the tutorial subdirectory.

You might also be interested in some of the surrounding discussion, which is all about  the process of comparing new models with the existing ones.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool I'll check it out, thanks!